# Souls (Neshamos) of converts

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, mysticism-kabbalah, soul, arizal

When I was in Yeshiva many years ago I heard one of the rebbeim (teachers) of the yeshiva speaking to a young man that had converted to Judaism and that was very successful in learning about "his status" in regards to certain halachos (that perhaps might not be nohag now a days) and how a convert is different.

One of the things the Rabbi said was that "you should know the Ari Zal writes that the neshemas (souls) of a convert comes from the 'highest places' in Shamayim." Now I realize this hard to perhaps understand what a soul coming from a high place really means but it was meant to show how "special" this person really is.

Is it known where this is brought down from the Ari Zal or in any other sifrei kabballah or sefer at all?

Comment: Zohar in parshat Bereshit says that the physical union of a tzaddik and his wife that does not conceive a child is not in vain. That union creates the souls that converts receive when they convert.

Comment: @Menachem  very good, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @mike. I'd have to find it inside.

Comment: @Menachem How is that relevant?

Comment: @HaLeiVi: That is a high source

Comment: @Menachem yes, find the source and post it!

Comment: @Menachem What does that have to do with having a higher soul (which I doubt)?

Comment: http://m.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380532/jewish/Soul-of-the-Convert.htm

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/1161280/ and http://www.chabad.org/380829/